# Possible bug when creating arcs using Circle[…]

Tags: regions, geometry

The documentation for the Circle function states that the optional third parameter, $\left\{\theta _1,\theta _2\right\}$, "gives a circular or ellipse arc from angle $\theta _1$ to $\theta _2$." But when used to create an arc of a non-circular ellipse the result is incorrect, i.e., does not run from $\theta _1$ to $\theta _2$.

For example, these two arcs use the same starting and ending angles yet the circular arc (`circleArc`) is correct and the non-circular arc (`ellipseArc`) is not:

```
1=π/6; 2=2π/6;
circleArc = Circle[{0,0},1,{1,2}]
ellipseArc = Circle[{0,0},{2,1},{1,2}]
```

Displaying them along with lines showing the desired starting and ending angles show that the non-circular arc (red) is incorrect:

```
1 = π/6; 2 = 2π/6;
lines = {
   Rotate[InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 0}], 1, {0, 0}],
   Rotate[InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, {1, 0}], 2, {0, 0}]};
circle = Circle[{0, 0}, 1];
circleArc = Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {1, 2}];
ellipse = Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}];
ellipseArc = Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}];
Graphics[{Thickness[Medium], Gray, lines,
  Thin, circle, ellipse,
  Thick, Green, circleArc, Red, ellipseArc},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2.1}, {0, 1.1}}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True]
```

[image]
The error appears to be due to using the starting and ending angles as the bounds for the parameter `t` in the parametric equation of an ellipse. For example, for the ellipse defined by the following:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[2 t], Sin[t]}, {t, start, end};
```

`start` and `end` specify the bounds for the parameter `t` which are not the starting and ending angles of the arc it is circular.

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because it is not a practical, answerable question (or a question at all). Bug reports and suggestions about changes to Mathematica should be addressed to Wolfram Research directly. Note that this site is not affiliated with Wolfram Research.

Comment: Should be `ParametricPlot[{2Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, start, end}`

Comment: "using the starting and ending angles as the bounds for the parameter t in the parametric equation of an ellipse" - that's how it's been since version 1 (i.e. *by design*).

Comment: `Show[Graphics[
  ellipseArc = Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {π/6, 2 π/6}]], 
 ParametricPlot[{2 Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, π/6, 
   2 π/6}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.2], AbsoluteThickness[10], Red}]]`. Not bug here.

Comment: @J.M. It's also stated explicitly [in the docs, under Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html#164313953).

Comment: The docs state: "`Circle[{x,y},{rx,ry}]` represents the axis-aligned filled ellipse in R^2 with center `{x,y}` and semiaxis lengths `rx` and `ry`, and `Circle[{x,y},\[Ellipsis],{θ1,θ2}]` represents the (potentially elliptical) arc centered at {x,y} ranging between ***angles `θ1` and `θ2` measured in radians counterclockwise from the positive x axis.***" (emphasis mine) The emphasized part is wrong. I don't ever recall radian measure being redefined for an ellipse so that the measure of an angle depends on which ellipse or circle in a figure one is looking at....

Comment: ...The definition would be accurate if it described the effect of the radii `{rx,ry}` as scaling the unit circle/arc.

Comment: @Michael, yeah, that part could be written better. Perhaps OP or someone else can make a better phrasing before reporting to Support...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sure, the docs are inaccurate, and this could be reported to WRI. But the post still doesn't fit SE at all. It's not even a question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Agreed. [*Added later: It's also easy to test which description is accurate.*]

Comment: @Szab I wrote "Possible bug…?" (with a question mark) in my title but maybe should have in the post too. The documentation gives both wrong and right details to specify the arc: in the function's description (that I spoke of in my first sentence) as well as in the Details: the 3rd picture just before what you say is "explicitly stated in the doc…", shows the arc incorrectly running from 1 to 2. It confused me and easily may others as well. If someone questions this they'll more likely find the answer here than at Wolfram (among the 27 pages of "possible bugs" posted for this community.)